# JMS and JBoss setup for standalone applications

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, jms

I'm writing an application that runs as a daemon and makes `restful` request periodically, I'm trying to implement a system where I have another application (preprocessor) that will be sent the `JSON` responses from the daemon.

My plan is to use `JMS` for this, my understanding is that I can send the `restful`  responses I receive in my `daemon.jar` to a `Queue` using a JMS provider, I've been looking into using JBoss.

I'm struggling to find a good example that walks me through setting up `JBoss` in IntelliJ and some sender / receiver code.

I'v been trying to use the code provided here: [JMS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jms/j-jms-updated.html)

But I'm unsure how `JBoss` is used in all this, I have a Jboss server environment setup in intelliJ, but I don't think that's what I need, this will be a standalone application. How do the sender and receiver use JBoss?

Is this a good way to do what I'm trying to do?